# c# mongodb driver how to cast a mongo double value to a c# decimal one

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have this bson document which I read from mongodb, using c# mongodb driver v2.4.4. I just need to convert some field in it to decimal in a c# code. I know there is a double value there, therefore I try to convert to a decimal value using:

```
monto = Convert.ToDecimal(document["monto"].AsDouble)
```

But, as the value is *39330000*, I suppose the driver assumes it is a Int32 and throws this exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonInt32' to type
>   'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDouble'.

Maybe because it doesn't come with the dot (.) in it.

So, I'm using this to convert to decimal:

```
monto = Convert.ToDecimal(document["monto"].ToString())
```

And it works because c# can convert to decimal any string that contains a number.

My question is: is there a better way to convert a bson double to c# decimal, without converting it to a string first ?

Thanks and bye ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option would probably to go with this:

```
monto = document["monto"].ToDecimal();
```

The reason why this works so nicely is that the abstract `BsonValue` type implements a method that looks like this:

```
public virtual decimal ToDecimal()
```

The concrete implementations of `BsonValue` (e.g. `BsonInt32`, `BsonInt64`, `BsonDouble` etc.) override this member with the below method which gives you precisely what you want, no matter if the driver deserializes an int, a long or a double from a stored document:

```
public override decimal ToDecimal()
{
    return (decimal)_value;
}
```

Alternatively, in your specific case (and if all documents in scope have an int stored in their "monto" field) you can simply write:

```
monto = Convert.ToDecimal(document["monto"].AsInt32)
```

or even just

```
monto = (decimal)(document["monto"].AsInt32)
```

which are semantically identical.

Comment: Thanks @dnickless, I just did it by using "document["monto"].ToDecimal()". Converting instead of casting, as Kanders said. Thanks again ...

Comment: Under the hoods this call does nothing but a cast (for an Int32 at least) but that's the fastest, shortest and cleanest way.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the error you're getting, it seems that the type is stored as an integer, not as a double.

In either case, you can do it by converting instead of casting. That is, just use `ToDouble()` instead of `AsDouble`. This: `document["monto"].ToDouble();` will get you back the double directly, though it still throws exceptions if the type can't be converted in an obvious way...

```
BsonDocument bdoc = new BsonDocument()
{
    { "three", 3 },
    { "pi", 3.14 },
    { "e", "2.71" },
    { "true", true },
    { "arr", new BsonArray() }
};
double three = bdoc["three"].ToDouble();    // three = 3.0
double pi = bdoc["pi"].ToDouble();       // pi = 3.14
double e = bdoc["e"].ToDouble();         // e = 2.71
double t = bdoc["true"].ToDouble(); // throws NotSupportedException
double arr = bdoc["arr"].ToDouble(); // throws NotSupportedException
```

Comment: "... you can do it by converting instead of casting". Wow, I think this is huge, at least for me ...

Answer (score 0):

Try using typed objects then you won't need to bother with converting them yourself.

Here I have a Product with that have a few different types for the price but in this model I want them all to come back as a decimal:

```
public class Product
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Int32Price { get; set; }

    public decimal StringPrice { get; set; }

    public decimal Decimal128Price { get; set; }
}
```

We can then push some data in to mongodb

```
var mongoDatabase = new MongoClient().GetDatabase("test");
var untypedCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("products");
var doc = new BsonDocument()
{
    {"Name", "Shampoo" },
    {"Int32Price", BsonInt32.Create(33) },
    {"StringPrice", BsonString.Create("33.45") },
    {"Decimal128Price", BsonDecimal128.Create(33.45m) },
};
untypedCollection.InsertOne(doc);
```

then get it back out using our typed object:

```
var productCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Product>("products");

var product = productCollection.Find(x => x.Id == doc["_id"]).First();

Console.WriteLine(product.Id);
Console.WriteLine(product.Name);
Console.WriteLine(product.Int32Price);
Console.WriteLine(product.StringPrice);
Console.WriteLine(product.Decimal128Price);

// 5a0c581b1a1c8f310049815a
// Shampoo
// 33
// 33.45
// 33.45
```

Comment: Kevin, thanks for your answer. Then items are not written by the c# app, but by a javascript app. That's why I don't know exactly how they are going to come. I the js app they all should be doubles. I think that mongo, when does not find the need, does not put the dot (.) in the number. That's why the driver in c# reads an integer and not a double. That's this makes any sense? ...