# MongoDB cast to C# int

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a MongoDB database with some fields that are "number", which means some are double, int, etc. Basically JavaScript number. I would like to read those fields and cast them to integer. I have tried `(int)(document["someField"].AsDouble)` and I get an error that int cannot be cast to double. Then I try `document["someField"].AsInt32` and I get an exception that double cannot be cast to int. The "document" in this case is `BsonDocument`. How do I read a "number" and cast it to int?

Comment: Have you tried Convert? `int i = Convert.ToInt32(document["someField"]);`

Comment: or you can even try `Convert.ToInt32(document["someField"].AsDouble)`, remember there might be data loss

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309945/c-sharp-mongodb-driver-how-to-cast-a-mongo-double-value-to-a-c-sharp-decimal-one only change `ToInt32`